# Next.js fetched data comes in, but I can't get it to display on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios, tanstack

I can get the data to show up in a `console.log` from the first file, where it is being grabbed by axios, but can't get it to display in my tanstack table or just as a string inside the HTML. I have tested my tanstack table with hardcoded data and it worked great. Included is an image of the console, with the data showing, between `help1` and `help2`, but not between `dell1` and `dell2`.

File `ProjectsTableBlock`:

```js
import React, { ReactNode, useEffect } from "react";
import Block from "./Block";
import Button from "../Button";
import Table from "../Table";

import { createColumnHelper } from "@tanstack/react-table";
import axios from "axios";

type ProjectsTableBlockProps = {
    block_span: string;
    children: ReactNode;
};

type Project = {
    project_id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    organization_id: number;
};

const columnHelper = createColumnHelper<Project>();

const columns = [
    columnHelper.accessor("project_id", {
        header: () => "Project ID",
        cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
        footer: (info) => info.column.id,
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("name", {
        cell: (info) => <i>{info.getValue()}</i>,
        header: () => "Name",
        footer: (info) => info.column.id,
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("description", {
        header: "Description",
        cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
        footer: (info) => info.column.id,
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("organization_id", {
        header: "Organization ID",
        cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
        footer: (info) => info.column.id,
    }),
];

export default function ProjectsTableBlock(ProjectsTableBlockProps) {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState<Project[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get("/api/projects")
            .then((response) => {
                setData(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error("Error fetching projects:", error));
    }, []);

    console.log("help1");
    console.log(data);
    console.log("help2");

    return (
        <Block>
            <div className=" flex items-center justify-between pb-6">
                <div>
                    <h2 className="text-gray-600 font-semibold">Projects</h2>
                    <span className="text-xs">Projects List</span>
                </div>
                <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                    <div className="lg:ml-40 ml-10 space-x-8">
                        <Button action="Create">Create</Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div className="-mx-4 sm:-mx-8 px-4 sm:px-8 py-4 overflow-x-auto">
                    <div className="inline-block min-w-full shadow rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
                        <Table columns={columns} data={data}></Table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Block>
    );
}
```

File `Table.tsx`

```js
import { ViewColumnsIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import React, { useState } from "react";

import {
    createColumnHelper,
    flexRender,
    getCoreRowModel,
    useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";

type TableProps = {
    columns: any;
    data: any;
};

export default function Table(TableProps) {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(() => [...TableProps.data]);

    const table = useReactTable({
        data,
        columns: TableProps.columns,
        getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    });

    console.log("dell1");
    console.log(data);
    console.log("dell2");

    return (
        <div>
            <table className="min-w-full">
                <thead className="bg-white border-b">
                    {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
                        <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
                            {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                                <th key={header.id}>
                                    {header.isPlaceholder
                                        ? null
                                        : flexRender(
                                              header.column.columnDef.header,
                                              header.getContext()
                                          )}
                                </th>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
                        <tr className="bg-white border-b" key={row.id}>
                            {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                                <td
                                    className="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap"
                                    key={cell.id}
                                >
                                    {flexRender(
                                        cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                                        cell.getContext()
                                    )}
                                </td>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

[image]

I expected the data to get displayed in the tanstack table or at least show up in the `console log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

You declared an empty `data` array state in `ProjectsTableBlock`, which gets updated after the data is fetched via `axios`. But you gave that initial empty array to `Table` as part of `props` and used it to create an internal state called `data`. And the thing about `useState`, is that the initial `state` can only be updated by calling `setState`.

## Solution

One way to fix your issue is to remove the inner state, and use the props, like so:

```js
export default function Table(TableProps) {
  // const [data, setData] = React.useState(() => [...TableProps.data]); 

  const table = useReactTable({
      // 
      data: TableProps.data, 
      columns: TableProps.columns,
      getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  });

  console.log("dell1");
  console.log(TableProps.data);
  console.log("dell2");

  //...

}
```

Or, if you need to manipulate that inner `data` state, make sure inside `ProjectsTableBlock` that you only render `Table` after the data is fully fetched, like so:

```js
{data.length > 0 && <Table columns={columns} data={data}></Table>}
```

Very often, you would wanna show a loader in place:

```js
{data.length > 0 ? <Table columns={columns} data={data}></Table> : "Loading..."}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was perfect. The extra tip for including loading was useful. I can't help but feel a little ashamed I didn't notice, I was using a different variable. Trying to learn Next.js, not much of a front-end developer at the moment.